# Using DTX Metafonts as system fonts

Tags: conversion, metafont

Dear Stack Exchange team,

I am a relatively inexperienced user of LaTeX who is currently working on a project which also requires the use of an image editing tool, in this case GIMP.
As I would like to preserve visual coherence across the project, I was looking for a way to install DTX Metafonts on my system so that I could use them in GIMP. Most importantly, the fonts I'd like to use are the egothic and tgothic packages available at CTAN.

However, the only way I could find to do so (http://metatype.sourceforge.net/faq.php) requires a tedious and complicated procedure of converting the glyphs to TTF one by one.

Is there any other way known to you of converting the DTX font? Do you know of anyone who has already transformed these two typefaces to a usable system font?

Best regards

Jonathan Nordmann

Comment: your question is very unclear can you add some links to reference the terms you are using, I can find no reference anywhere of a font format known as dtx metafont?

Comment: simplest is to use luatex then you can use system truetype or opentype fonts and gimp can use the same fonts.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Since I posted the question, someone has sent me the fonts as PostScript which I could then convert to OpenType in FontForge.